# predictive modelling pipeline with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've been moving gradually from `R` to `Python` to do some predictive modelling. I want to know what is the best pipeline to do hyperparameter optimization with cross validation and apply the trained model to new instances.

Below you will see a quick example I did using random forest. I want to know if this is ok and what would you add or remove from it?

```
#import data sets
train_df = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv') 
test_df = pd.read_csv('../input/test.csv')

#get the predictors only
X_train = train_df.drop(["ID", "target"], axis=1) 
y_train = np.log1p(train_df["target"].values)  

X_test = test_df.drop(["ID"], axis=1)

#grid to do the random search

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV 

n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)] 
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
bootstrap = [True, False]  

# Create the random grid
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
           'max_features': max_features,
           'max_depth': max_depth,
           'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
           'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
           'bootstrap': bootstrap}

#Create the model to tune
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_random= RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 100, cv = 10, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs =10)
#fit the random search model
rf_random.fit(X_train, y_train) 

#get the best estimator
best_random = rf_random.best_estimator_ 

# train again with the best parameters on the whole training data?
best_random.fit(X_train,y_train)

#apply the best predictor to the test set
pred_test_rf = np.expm1(best_random.predict(X_test))
```

1. Is `.best_estimator_` instantiating the model with the best parameters found in the grid search?
2. If so, do I need to retrain again (as I did above) with the whole training data or is it already retrained?
3. I'd like to know whether this approach is ok or what are some best practices to do this using sklearn in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes its an estimator initiated with `best_params_` from the `rf_random`

2) No, its trained on the whole data already, no need to do `best_random.fit(X_train,y_train)`

RandomizedSearchCV has a param `'refit'` which is `True` by default:

> ```
> refit : boolean, or string default=True
>         Refit an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.
> ```

3) Your approach seems ok. This is the standard way. Other things may depend on various things like type of data, size of data, the algorithm (estimator) used, the time you have to explore the possibilities etc. But this part is best suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com.